# Compile FFMpeg as .net executable

Tags: .net, c, ffmpeg, cil

Has anyone tried to compile FFMpeg as CIL executable? I mean: I found wrappers for FFMpeg in order to integrate FFMpeg in a .net program, but it should be possible to compile it as managed code, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is certainly possible is to write your own managed app that links with libavformat, libavcodec, etc., as long as the latter has been pre-built as a DLL or a static library. [Here you can find Windows-specific FFmpeg (and libav*.*) builds](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/). These libraries (not the exe) can safely be part of a managed app if you use P/Invoke (for the DLLs) or static linking (for the LIBs).

Building FFMpeg itself as a managed app *might* be possible ([here at least are FFMpeg build instructions for Visual Studio](http://www.ffmpeg.org/platform.html#toc-Microsoft-Visual-C_002b_002b-or-Intel-C_002b_002b-Compiler-for-Windows)), although I have never tried.

Comment: Inline assembly is the issue. Ok, that's what I needed to know.

Comment: C99 support is also the issue, which still isn't supported in Visual Studio.

Comment: Perhaps it's time to update this answer, as [FFmpeg can now be built with Microsoft Visual C++](http://www.ffmpeg.org/faq.html#Is-Microsoft-Visual-C_002b_002b-supported_003f).

Comment: @haneefmubarak  thanks - have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Now that I think about it, we could probably have done it with C++Builder, which is compliant with C11 and generates .net executables.